# Excel: Find duplicates in column with differences in another column

Tags: excel, formatting, excel-formula, compare

I want to highlight cells in column A, which have duplicates in column A but a difference in column B.

```
A   B  
1   2   -
2   3   +
3   2   -
2   4   +
1   2   -
3   2   -
4   5   -
```

The rows (or a cell within the row) with the - shall not be highlighted, but the rows (or a cell within the row) with the + shall be highlighted.

How can I accomplish this in an Excel formula?

Please pay attention to the fact, that not all unique combinations shall be highlighted (last row!).

In SQL the corresponding query would be something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
GROUP BY A
HAVING COUNT(B) > 1
```

Comment: hello, are you flexible in the workbook to use an empty column to combine 2 rows so you can search rest for the repeating value?

Comment: Hi Dubison, yes, I can change the workbook and use so far unused cells. I see, where this is going... it's so obvious, thank you!

Comment: P. S. No, it's not. Had a wrong thought. Why do you ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark column A > Home > Style > Conditional Formatting> New Rule... > Use a formula to determine which cells to format > enter the formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A=A1),--(B:B<>B1))
```

> Format... > choose some formatting of your liking > OK > OK

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution might be to use `Concatenate` to join A and B together and use a conditional formating to highlight the unique values. This would leave your desired list highlighted:

[image]

For the Conditional Formatting highlight column C then navigate:

Home-> Conditional Formatting -> New Rule-> Format only unique or duplicate values

Then change selection from "duplicate" to "unique" and select the desired format.  Apply the setting and have identified the appropriate rows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this would highlight ALL unique combinations, but I just want those highlighted, which - to stick to your example - have a duplicate in column A. Adding row 8 in you example with A8=4 and B8=7 would be highlighted, but 4 does not have a duplicate in A!

Comment: Ah, yes.  Very true.  Perhaps you could combat that with Frequency formula in the conditional formatting.  Let me think on that...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in A1:B7, (with "A" and "B" as headers on row 1):

I used the following formulas to get the matches ..
I just did a simple search after, and before .. if it finds a record above or below, it "flags" it in column F as TRUE.
Not sure it works for 3 or more duplicates, though you didn't seem to indicate how you wanted a 3 of a kind to work ;)

```
D2=MATCH(A2,A3:$A$1000,0)
E2=IF(ISERROR(D2),IF(ISERROR(G2),"",OFFSET($A$1,G2,0,1,1)),OFFSET(B2,D2,0,1,1))
F2=AND(NOT(AND(ISERROR(D2),ISERROR(G2))),B2<>E2)
G2=MATCH(A2,$A$1:A1,0)`
```

D col locates the first matching A column after the current row.

G col locates the first matching A Column prior to current row.

E col pulls that remote B column value to current row to more easily check.

F col puts the logic together: If we found something, and B cols are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it assuming your above data is in cells `A2:B7`:

1)  Copy and paste your column A values to a blank section of your workbook(Lets say `A11`) and perform the following function `Data->Remove Duplicates` with the section selected.

2)  Highlight cells B10:B13(all cells where a value is in column A) and type in the following formula:

```
=FREQUENCY(A2:A8,A10:A13)
```

Hit `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` to make this an array.

3) Similar to step two highlight all cells in column C where there is data in columns A and B.  In this case `C2:C7` and use the following formula:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A2,$A$10:$B$13,2,FALSE)>1,IF(FREQUENCY(VALUE(CONCATENATE($A$2:$A$7,$B$2:$B$7)),VALUE(CONCATENATE($A$2:$A$7,$B$2:$B$7)))<>1,"","Highlight"),"")
```

Hit `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` to make this an array.

Your cells that need to be highlighted will now say "Highlight"

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Problem is, I want this function to be dynamically and work automatically on newly inserted values in a certain range, so C&P is out of the question, sorry.

Comment: If C&P is the only issue you can use this formula in a location to create you unique list assuming data is in the same location:

=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(0,IF(ISBLANK(A:A),"",COUNTIF(D$11:$D12,A:A)),0)),"")

Again using Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

If this option will work, let me know.  I am happy to outline it with this change in the Answer.